# Should a chat app running on Vue and Laravel use a Laravel queue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chat

Should a chat app running on Vue and Laravel use a Laravel queue? In Laravel, there is a `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync`, should that be used? Or, should some kind of queuing be used instead for a chat app? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about messages being placed into the queue or notifications?

Comment: Messages.What are notifications?

Comment: Ok well I don’t use a queue for messages, but I don’t see why you couldn’t. I guess it would depend on your rate of messages though.

Comment: Do you have a definitive answer at all?

Comment: No, it’s entirely up to you how you program your app lol... try it without a queue and if you encounter problems that could be fixed with a queue, implement the queue. Simple

Comment: Sure, thanks, appreciate it.